# Professor Bob's lab

Tags: pronouns, word-usage, abbreviations

I know "Bob's house" and "Bob's" mean the same thing.

Question 1: Is there a name for this grammatical phenomenon? 
Can one call it an abbreviation?

Question 2: In the context of within a university, can I simply call "Professor Bob's lab" "Professor Bob's"?

Example:
I am interested in the labs of Professors A, B and C. I also like Professor Bob's.

Is the example sentence formal and correct? Do people understand that I'm referring to the lab of Professor Bob?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just called...

> *[**deletion**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deletion) - any process whereby sounds or words are left out of spoken words or phrases.*

In OP's case the words *house* and *lab* are simply deleted. It gets a bit more complicated with, say, *"I liked his answer, but I didn't like **yours**"* (where the "full" version is ***your*** answer).